# Adding number of days to date to calculate end date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

I have table A with data. In query there is need to calculate end date which needed to be DATE+Num of Days. I tried with this but it's not usable:

```
DATEADD (day,NumOfDays,Date)
```

There is table A:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+
|  XPK   | Date       |  NumOfDays  |
+--------+------------+-------------+
|      1 | 2005-11-12 | 2           | 
|      2 | 2007-07-14 | 3           |
|      3 | 2000-04-22 | 4           |
+--------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by *but it's not usable:* ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Oh, damn... I just now realised that NumOfDays is varchar

Comment: Just do a explicit conversion to `int`. `DATEADD (day,cast(NumOfDays as int),Date)`

Comment: Working :D great, thanks